# Add a new Key: value pair into every existing array of a object JS, React.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I'm new to react and learning it at a get go paste. I'm building a small PokemonApp that gets its data through the PokemonAPI and it render's it to the web.

The only data that I'm fetching through the API is the Pokemon name and URL of the Pokemon. The component that fetches the data is called **getDataFromAPI** and it uses axios (promises) to get it. The data is stored in the **pokemoni** array and is displayed on the browser. The state shown through the Crome's React Dew Tools  is this.

```
State
 pokemoni: Array[20]
    0: {...}
       name: "metapod"
       url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"
    1: {...}
```

Now i wont to add a new [{key: value}] pair to all the existing objects that will change from false to true when the user clicks on a Pokemon that they got (it will be a button or something else). The state of the change by the user will  be made only once (from false to true).

```
State
     pokemoni: Array[20]
        0: {...}
           name: "metapod"
           url: "http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/11/"
           havePokemon: "false"
        1: {...}
```

The logic i came to was using .map() to add a new [{key: value}] pair  to all the existing objects. And doesn't work. Because i don't understand the problem. The function is located inside the **getDataFromAPI** component and it is called **updatePokemon**

```
var PokedexApp = React.createClass({
      componentDidMount: function(){
          this.getDataFromAPI();            
      },
      getDataFromAPI: function(){
         var that = this;

        PokemonAPI.getPokemonList().then(function (temp) {
          that.setState({
             pokemoni: temp,           
             isLoading: false
          });
         }, function (e) {            
            that.setState({
               isLoading: true
            });
         });


         //This function should update the array with a new key: value pair with the name  havePokemon 
         var updatePokemon = this.state.pokemoni.map(function(myPokemon){
             myPokemon.havePokemon= "false";
             return myPokemon;
         });
         this.setState({pokemoni: updatePokemon});

     },
     componentWillUnmount: function() {
          this.getDataFromAPI.abort();
     },    
     getInitialState: function() {
         return{
            showMyPokemon: false,
            searchPokemon: '',
            pokemoni: [],
            isLoading: false
        };
     }, 
    render: function(){
       var {pokemoni, showMyPokemon, searchPokemon} = this.state;
       var filteredPokemoni = PokemonLocalStorageAPI.filterPokemone(pokemoni, showMyPokemon, searchPokemon);

    return (
          <div>
              <h1 className="text-center page-title">PokedexApp</h1>
              <PokedexAppSearch onSearch={this.handleSearch} />
              <PokedexAppLista pokemoni={filteredPokemoni} onToggle={this.handleToggle}/>
          </div>
    )
}
});

module.exports = PokedexApp;
```

It does not work and i don't understand why. Ty in advance if u have the time to check my problem.

Comment: Do you have an initial state that includes `state.pokemoni?` As written, the mapping of the state.pokemoni will happen before the gertPokemonList() function resolves. So if the state.pokemoni only gets created after getPokemonList finishes, you have to palce the mapping inside the succes handler of the `then()` callback, so after `that.setState({pokemoni: temp, isLoading: false});` PS: You're also writing the string "false", if it's suppsoed to be a boolean, you'll have to change that aprt.

Comment: Ty for the answer. That did it, and still i don't get it. The pokemoni array is initialized in getInitalState. And then later populated in getPokemonList. So why did it fill inside the  succes handler of the then() callback, and not later in the updatePokemon function?

Comment: If the idea is to always map After the pokemons return from the API, it belongs inside the then handler, since it's an async function. If you write the mapping outside the then callback, the mapping will occur after getPokemonList() is called, but before the answer arrives from the server. Look up the differences between sync and async if you want to understand better. Basically your code won't pause as you wait for the server to answer, so any code written After the `getPokemonList()` will happen before the server answers. Once the serevr answers, the 'then' handler is called to update state.

Comment: Thank u weary much. now i get it :)